# Laravel form not sending any data

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to submit form to the laravel. However, I am facing strange issue that the form is being submitted without any data. When I tried to `print_r` on the cotroller it displays:

```
Array
(
)
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('amenityFront.index')}}" id="buildingByProperty">
    @csrf
    <select class="form-control" name="property" id="propertySelect">
        @foreach($properties as $pk => $pv)
            <option value="{{$pv->id}}" {{ ($pv->id == $selectedProperty)?'selected':'' }}>{{$pv->property_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is my route. Is it because of that match route? I am using this match route for first time.

Route:

```
    Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/', ['as' => 'amenityFront.index', 'uses' => 'AmenityController@index']);
```

### Update:

I have updated form to :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('amenityFront.postIndex')}}" id="buildingByProperty">
    @csrf
    <select class="form-control" name="property" id="propertySelect">
        @foreach($properties as $pk => $pv)
            <option value="{{$pv->id}}" {{ ($pv->id == $selectedProperty)?'selected':'' }}>{{$pv->property_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and updated route to:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'amenityFront.index', 'uses' => 'AmenityController@index']);
    Route::post('/', ['as' => 'amenityFront.postIndex', 'uses' => 'AmenityController@postIndex']);
```

However, instead of redirecting to postIndex I am still being posted to `@index`

My `route:list`

[image]

Comment: Try to add the ternary operation just one step above the option tag.

Comment: @CHARITRASHRESTHA could you elaborate little bit more.

Comment: How do you output the data? What does your controller method look like?

Comment: post your ```index``` method

Comment: public function index(Request $request)
    {
        print_r($request->all());
}

Comment: try to ```dd($request()->all());``` and see if there is any output

Comment: @AlanGe `$request()` won't work, it's either `$request` or `request()`

Comment: @kerbholz yep my bad it was a typo

Comment: @AlanGe I don't think there is much diffference between dd and print_r. Even though, I have tried with dd as well and its still empty array.

Comment: @AayushDahal Have you tried to use ```post``` instead of ```match```? ```Route::post('/','AmenityController@index')->name('amenityFront.index');```

Comment: @AlanGe Please read the question, I have updated it.

Comment: clear the cache : ```php artisan cache:clear``` ```php artisan route:clear``` and ```php artisan view:clear``` and see if you get the same result ..the comment section will be a mess [join the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/199104/laravel-stuff) is better to discuss your problem

Comment: I have tried all but same result